# How to define class structure for custom XML format

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Hi I have the xml format defined for which i need to serialize from my object.
My XML will look like :

```xml
<PerfCheckConsidered>
    <PerfMarker PercentageIncrease="21.4171662006946" MaxValue="6650.55" MinValue="5477.438" TS_09082021093913="5961.733" TS_09082021093646="6650.55" TS_09082021093358="5477.438" TS_09082021093136="5510.135" TS_09082021092614="5768.742" PerfMarkerName="Marker1"/>
    
    <PerfMarker PercentageIncrease="20.9911157408996" MaxValue="7371.881" MinValue="6092.911" TS_09082021093913="7371.881" TS_09082021093646="6092.911" TS_09082021093358="6345.139" TS_09082021093136="6289.624" TS_09082021092614="6782.205" PerfMarkerName="Marker1"/>
    
    <PerfMarker PercentageIncrease="9.22930544021455" MaxValue="6183.199" MinValue="5660.751" TS_09082021093913="6183.199" TS_09082021093646="5660.751" TS_09082021093358="6000.608" TS_09082021093136="5951.08" TS_09082021092614="5870.288" PerfMarkerName="Marker1"/>
    
    <PerfMarker PercentageIncrease="25.0711884164738" MaxValue="10075.0518" MinValue="8055.4538" TS_09082021093913="10062.1176" TS_09082021093646="10061.7749" TS_09082021093358="10075.0518" TS_09082021093136="8055.4538" TS_09082021092614="10063.9758" PerfMarkerName="Marker2"/>
    
    <PerfMarker PercentageIncrease="13.2855819181415" MaxValue="8250.0617" MinValue="7282.5346" TS_09082021093913="8237.9737" TS_09082021093646="8245.9522" TS_09082021093358="8240.958" TS_09082021093136="8250.0617" TS_09082021092614="7282.5346" PerfMarkerName="Marker2"/>
    
    <PerfMarker PercentageIncrease="29.7888969731873" MaxValue="50.4823" MinValue="38.8957" TS_09082021093913="50.4823" TS_09082021093646="46.8748" TS_09082021093358="38.8959" TS_09082021093136="38.8957" TS_09082021092614="40.8915" PerfMarkerName="Marker3"/>
    
    <PerfMarker PercentageIncrease="54.5326940955576" MaxValue="16.9544" MinValue="10.9714" TS_09082021093913="11.9676" TS_09082021093646="12.9662" TS_09082021093358="16.9544" TS_09082021093136="10.9714" TS_09082021092614="10.9714" PerfMarkerName="Marker3"/>
    
    <PerfMarker PercentageIncrease="14.028196761682" MaxValue="64.8256" MinValue="56.8505" TS_09082021093913="60.8377" TS_09082021093646="62.8326" TS_09082021093358="56.8505" TS_09082021093136="59.2591" TS_09082021092614="64.8256" PerfMarkerName="Marker3"/>
    
    <PerfMarker PercentageIncrease="8.33604893089013" MaxValue="25.9311" MinValue="23.9358" TS_09082021093913="25.9311" TS_09082021093646="23.9358" TS_09082021093358="25.93" TS_09082021093136="25.9306" TS_09082021092614="24.9344" PerfMarkerName="Marker3"/>
    
</PerfCheckConsidered>
```

Here in above XML, TagName like TS_09082021093913,TS_09082021093646,TS_09082021093136,TS_09082021092614 are not known in compile time, These are TimeStamp Names formed from files names present in local disk.

How should i define my object structure to fill data of this kind

Current class looks like (From this structure i cannot get the desired xml format)

```cs
 
public class PerfCheck
{
        
        public string PerfMarkerName { get; set; }

        
        public string PercentageIncrease { get; set; }

        
        public string MaxValue { get; set; }

         
        public string MinValue { get; set; }


        
       public string Marker { get; set; }

     
       public List<TimeStampToInstances> TimeStampToMarkerValues { get; set; 
 
}

[Serializable]
public class TimeStampToInstances
{
    
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }

    
    public List<double> InstancesValues { get; set; }
}
```

Currently i am using my Custom logic to form the XML, But i am told to use normal xml serialization and try to modify the class structure to accommodate xml format
Is this possible ?

Comment: See: XmlAnyAttributeAttribute - however, your classes seem to have nothing whatsoever in common with the shown xml

Comment: As of now i am getting below values as List<TimeStampToInstances> - TS_09082021093913,TS_09082021093646,TS_09082021093136,TS_09082021092614 . But with this class structure, i cant achieve the required XML Format. So is there a way serialize current class structure to shown xml format ?

Comment: The existing class? No, none whatsoever - at least, not via standard inbuilt library handling

Comment: So duplicate of [How to deserialize element with list of attributes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32884364/3744182) and/or [C# XML deserialize all attributes as a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18231725/3744182) then?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your valuable inputs.

I was able to achieve required XML format by using dynamic object.
I Serialized my dynamic object to intermediate XML, From which i created my XML in required format.